# Given a countable union of countable sets in $\mathbb{R}$, must at least one of them be dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

Given a countable union of sets in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\cup A_i = \mathbb{R}$, must at least one of them be dense in $\mathbb{R}$? And, if the answer is yes, can anyone tell how I can prove it?

Comment: Does countable imply infinite for you? Have you tried some examples?

Comment: Uncountable sets can be nowhere dense (like the Cantor set), so we can partition the Cantor Set into an uncountable number of disjoint countable sets using the Axiom of Choice--none of them can be dense.

Comment: Presumably you want the union to be dense in $\mathbb R$

Comment: Yes, it seems something is missing...

Comment: Sorry! What I ment is: Given a countable union of sets in R, $A_i$ such that $\cup A_i = R$, Must one of them be dense in R?
of course, if the union is not R one can look at the integers as a countable union of countable sets. sorry for not pointing that out in the first time.
Or another question that mught help me: if a set is not countable, must it be dense in some open segment of R?
Thanks!

Comment: @user60164: (You should probably have made this into a comment to your original question.)

A countable union of countable sets is countable, while $\mathbb{R}$ is not. Perhaps you mean, as suggested by others, that that union is *dense* in $\mathbb{R}$?

But then DaanMichiels has already given a counterexample.

Comment: @user60164: It seems you have accrued two separate accounts. Using the same account will allow you to comment on answers to your questions, and to edit your own posts to incorporate changes and suggestions. If you want your two separate accounts combined, please [visit this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Assuming that the Axiom of Choice holds, how can $ \mathbb{R} $ be the countable union of countable sets?

Comment: Sorry again, Yhe sets themselfs are not all countable

Comment: I've changed the question with respect to the last modification (which required $\mathbf R$ to be countable, a tall order), to something (requireing the union to be dense, rather than all of $\mathbf R$) that may or may not have been intended by OP. The answer is still obviously "no" though.

Comment: Excuse me, I hadn't seen the answer by (presumably) OP. So I've rolled back my edit and removed one "countable" instead (I hope I got it right this time).

Comment: After two more clarifications, the real question is:  Can $\mathbb R$ be partitioned into a countable collection of nowhere dense sets?  user60955:  If I got it right please edit in or ask me to by pinging me with a comment including @Ross

Answer (score 6):

No. For each prime $p_j$ consider the sets $S_j=\{p_j^k:k\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$. Each of these sets is countable and disjoint. Their union does not even cover the positive integers.

---

**Modified Question**

We cannot deduce that one of the $A_i$ is dense, but we can get that one must be dense somewhere; that is, $\overline{A_i}$ contains an interval.

Suppose that none of the $A_i$ are anywhere dense. Then $\overline{A_i}$ contains no intervals, that is $\overline{A_i}^\complement$ is open and dense. The [Baire Category Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) says that
$$
\bigcap_i\overline{A_i}^\complement=\left(\bigcup_i\overline{A_i}\right)^\complement=\mathbb{R}^\complement=\{\}
$$
is dense (contradiction). Thus, one of the $A_i$ must be somewhere dense.

Note that given an interval $[a,b]$, the argument above can be localized to show that for some $A_i$, $\overline{A_i}\cap[a,b]$ contains an interval.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is surely no. Take a countable number $(\alpha_i)$ of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ independent over $\mathbb Q$. Then let $X_i$ be the set of all elements of $[0,1]$ that equal $\alpha_i$ mod $\mathbb Q$. Then the $X_i$ are all countable. The union lies in $[0,1]$ so it cannot be dense in $\mathbb R$.

Note that, in my example, all the $X_i$ are disjoint (which you didn't require).

Answer (score 2):

**In response to the latest edit**

Suppose that the Axiom of Choice holds. Then a countable union of countable sets is countable. As $ \mathbb{R} $ is uncountable, it follows that $ \mathbb{R} $ cannot be a countable union of countable sets.

There exists a model $ \mathcal{M} $ of the Zermelo-Fraenkel (ZF) axioms whose set of real numbers $ \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{M}} $ is a countable union of countable sets. This is Theorem 10.6 of Thomas Jech’s *The Axiom of Choice*. Clearly, the Axiom of Choice must fail in $ \mathcal{M} $.

Therefore, you should be asking:

> For all models $ \mathcal{M} $ of ZF, if $ \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{M}} $ is a countable union of countable sets, is it true that one of those countable sets has to be dense?

Comment: This answer makes it sound that the two things are equivalent, while they are clearly not. The axiom of choice may fail acutely and the real numbers are not a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: @Asaf: I’ve clarified my presentation in response to your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Now it's much more accurate! :-) I still think that this answer shoots way way over the OP's head.

Answer (score 1):

*This is an answer to the original question, asking whether a countable family of countable sets must have a member that is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. (I have answered the question under the restriction that their union is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, even though it was not in the original question.)*

No. For any natural number $n$, take $X_n$ to be the set of rational numbers in $(n,n+1)$. Then the $X_n$ form a counterexample (indeed, the $X_n$ contain only positive numbers so are not dense in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: These are each dense somewhere, but you are correct they are not dense in all of $mathbb R$

Answer (score 1):

If you want the union of the countable sets to be dense in $\mathbb R$, take the union to be $\mathbb Q$.  Enumerate the rationals in $[0,1)$ as $q_i$.  Now let $S_i=q_i+z, z \in \mathbb Z$.  Each $S_i$ looks like the integers, so is not dense, but the union is all of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Your construction also gives disjoint sets $S_i$, very nice.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as modified by myself (a second time), even if $\bigcup A_i=\mathbf R$ and $i$ ranges over a countables set, there is no reason for any of the $A_i$ to be dense. Consider $A_i=\{\,x\in\mathbf R\mid \lfloor x\rfloor=i\,\}$ for $i\in\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Try $A_i=[-i,i]$                                   $ $